# check if the date is earlier than today

Tags: javascript

```
   alert(date2);//Sat Oct 29 0112 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) 
   alert(date1);//Fri Oct 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

if (date1.getTime()<date2.getTime()) {
     alert('your date can not be earlier than today.');
}
```

My question is why i don't see the alert? There is something wrong?

edit:

```
var today = new Date();
date2 = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
```

why this show the year as 0112??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getFullYear()`, not `getYear()`.

On some implementations getYear() returns the number of years since 1900. This is why you are getting 112 for the year.

Comment: Not "some", but **all** implementations consistent with ECMA-262 (see [`Date.prototype.getYear`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.4))

Comment: Older versions of IE do not conform then.

Comment: For dates 1900 to 1999, they do. But for dates outside that range, they don't. Guess it's one of those "it seemed like a good idea at the  time" things. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your date 1 is in year 2012 and your date2 is in year 112, you test if date1 is inferior to date2. Year 2012 is superior to year 112, so nothing is wrong here

Comment: well, so the problem is about 0112. Why? i will edit my question

Comment: @user947462 see my answer for why you are getting 112

Answer (score 3):

First you split both dates as different values for its month, day and year. You may use an array of months to find out the number for month. Then:

```
var date1 = new Date;
var date2 = new Date;
date1.setDate(29);
date1.setMonth(10);
date1.setFullYear(2012);

date2.setDate(12);
date2.setMonth(10);
date2.setFullYear(2012);

if(date1>date2)
alert('Date1 is greater');
else
alert('Date2 is greater');
```

Comment: That's great if you get paid by the yard. :-) Much more concise to pass values directly to the Date constructor: `var date1 = new Date(2012,9,29);`

Comment: Ya, you are right.. I have posted this in detail to let the question's owner to know how to set values individually for date, month and year as well. Anyway, thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well date 1 is in 2012 and date 2 is in 0112 so date 2 is before date 1, hence why you are not seeing the alert.

Answer (score 0):

year of date2 is 0112 and of date1 is 2012